# Utilizando um select com UNION ou outro parametro mysql

Tags: php, mysql, query, union-all

Estou desenvolvendo fluxo de caixa da minha empresa e estou encontrando uma dificuldade.

Eu tenho duas tabelas diferentes. Uma tabela é a `tb_compras(id, fornecedor, nfe, valor, data)` e então tenho outra tabela `tb_compras_historico_pagamentos(id, id_compra, valor_pago, data)`.

Eu preciso criar uma conta corrente igual de banco, fluxo de caixa de um determinado **FORNECEDOR** meu.

Eu vou lançando as compras na `tabela tb_compras` que no caso é um **débito(-)** e os pagamentos na `tabela tb_compras_historico_pagamentos` que no caso são os **créditos(+)**. 
Então tb_compras é o débito e tb_compras_historico_pagamentos é o crédito.

Ex:

```
Data | Descrição        | Crédito | Débito | Total
12/06 Cupom fiscal 02               -100,00 -100,00
13/06 Depósito 233        +80,00            -20,00
15/06 Cupom fiscal 11               -200.00 -220.00
17/06 Depósito 1223       +400,00           +180,00
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer o select para pegar os resultados das duas tabelas em um único select e ordenar pela data pra poder listar da forma do exemplo acima. 
Lembrando que a tabela `tb_compras_historico_pagamentos` está relacionada com a tabela `tb_compras`.

Pensei em usar o select abaixo, mas está dando erro no select, não sei se ele é a forma ideal para isso.

Porque no caso eu preciso pegar todos os registros da tabela `tb_compras` e da tabela `tb_compras_historico_pagamentos`(que esta ligada com a tb_compras) e listar todos por ordem de data para criar o fluxo de caixa de entrada e pagamentos.

O select que estou tentando é esse, mas sem sucesso:

> SELECT valor FROM tb_compras WHERE
>   fornecedor = 'ID_FORNECEDOR' UNION ALL SELECT valor FROM
>   tb_compras_historico_pagamento WHERE id_compra =
>   tb_compras.id

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você precisa fazer um inner join, recuperar os valores da tabela de históricos relativas ao débito.

```
SELECT A.valor as debito, B.valor as recebido FROM tb_compras A INNER JOIN tb_compras_historico_pagamento B ON A.id_compra = B.id_compra;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para versões de MySQL >= 8.0,

```
WITH RECURSIVE Q (rowid, data, fornecedor, credito, debito, saldo) AS
(
    SELECT C.id, C.data, C.fornecedor, HCRED.valor_pago as credito, HDEB.valor_pago as debito, COALESCE(HDEB.valor_pago, 0) + COALESCE(HCRED.valor_pago, 0) as saldo
    FROM      tb_compras C
    LEFT JOIN tb_compras_historico_pagamento HCRED
              ON C.id = HCRED.id_compra AND HCRED.valor_pago > 0
    LEFT JOIN tb_compras_historico_pagamento HDEB
              ON C.id = HDEB.id_compra AND HDEB.valor_pago < 0

    UNION

    SELECT C.data, C.fornecedor, HCRED.valor_pago, HDEB.valor_pago, COALESCE(HCRED.valor_pago, 0) + COALESCE(HDEB.valor_pago, 0) + Q.saldo
    FROM tb_compras C
    JOIN Q ON C.id = Q.rowid + 1
    LEFT JOIN tb_compras_historico_pagamento HCRED
              ON C.id = HCRED.id_compra AND HCRED.valor_pago > 0
    LEFT JOIN tb_compras_historico_pagamento HDEB
              ON C.id = HDEB.id_compra AND HDEB.valor_pago < 0
)
SELECT *
FROM Q
ORDER BY 2, 3;
```